# Getting mails for non subscribed content and no link to unsubscribe

Tags: bug, status-review, chat, spam, email

I got a mail from Stack Overflow regarding a chat event. I joined the chat event few months ago and this is the first time I'm getting a mail for that.

[image]

I checked my email subscription settings and mails for chat event is turned off. I didn't changed it for last 6+ months.

[image]

Comment: Screenshot is not relevant, the marked section is for the inbox, the email you got is not the inbox email.

Comment: @ShadowtheWelcomingWizard I can't find a way to turn off these. No unsubscribe button is there in the mail https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTHCw.png

Comment: Yeah, that's not nice and might be illegal in some countries. (Anti spam rules require any email from a company to have unsubscribe option.)

Comment: There are definitely legal implications in the United States. CAN-SPAM requires mailing list emails to have a true "unsubscribe" link, which doesn't require logging in or going to a settings page. (@Shadow time to bring out the "big guns")

Comment: not sure where but thought i'd read that email for chat events is sent when you have visited that chatroom recently

Comment: That's not true. I didn't visited that chat room for months. I'm getting email each and every week.

Comment: alright, perhaps add to your question that you definitely have not been in that chat room for months. also i find it interesting that i never get these messages even though i have all ticked except 'Features & Announcements', i'll try enabling that to see if i start getting them too..

Comment: @OptimusPrime you get this because you actively **registered** to the event, by this you agreed to get those notifications. To stop getting them you should simply unregister yourself from the event. I do agree this should be at least mentioned in the email with direct link, but still, easy enough to stop this if you really want.

Comment: I don't see you [registered for the event](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1337/smileycreations15s-meta-stack?tab=schedule) - guess you could try registering and unregistering, worst that could happen; well you know ...